# How do I write the not/negate higher order function in swift?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am a Javascripter and I love using the `not/negate` function:

```
function not (predicateFunc) {
    return function () {
        return !predicateFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing with swift:

```
func not <A> (_ f: @escaping (_ A: Any) -> Bool) -> (A) -> Bool {
    return { a in !f(a) }
}
```

But I am getting errors like

```
generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

and

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(Any) -> Bool'
```

The outcome I am looking for is when I have a function like this:

```
func isEmpty<T: Collection>(collection: T) -> Bool {
    return collection.count == 0
}
```

I can just create a `notEmpty` function like this:

```
let notEmpty = not(isEmpty)
```

And then use it like

```
   notEmpty([3,4,5]) // true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors:

- You're using `A` as both the type parameter and as the argument name.
- You're using `Any` as the argument type instead of using the type parameter (`A`) as the argument type.

Try this:

```
func not<A>(predicate: @escaping (A) -> Bool) -> (A) -> Bool {
    return { !predicate($0) }
}
```

Note that in this version, I'm not using argument names for the predicate argument. You don't need an argument name in the declaration (`(A) -> Bool`) and I'm using the anonymous argument name (`$0`) in the body.

---

Okay, so you want to write this:

```
func isEmpty<T: Collection>(collection: T) -> Bool {
    return collection.count == 0
}

func not<A>(_ predicate: @escaping (A) -> Bool) -> (A) -> Bool {
    return { !predicate($0) }
}

let notEmpty = not(isEmpty)
```

And you get this error:

```
let notEmpty = not(isEmpty)
               ^ Generic parameter 'A' could not be inferred
```

The problem is that this code tries to create a generic closure, but Swift doesn't support generic closures.

That is to say, what would the type of `nonEmpty` be? It would be something like:

```
<A: Collection>(A) -> Bool
```

and Swift doesn't support that.

Comment: nice! but I am getting a compiler error: `generic parameter 'A' could not be inferred`

Comment: @AmitErandole Obviously in declaration you have to tell the type to complier as `let notEmpty: ([Int])-> Bool = not(isEmpty)`

Answer (score 3):

Using `Any` is a code smell. You can just extend Collection directly:

```
extension Collection {
    var notEmpty: Bool {
        return !isEmpty
    }
}

[1, 3, 5].notEmpty // true
```

Your functional definition of `not` can work like this:

```
func not <A> (_ f: @escaping (_ a: A) -> Bool) -> (A) -> Bool {
    return { a in !f(a) }
}
```

But to call it you would need something like this:

```
let arrayNotEmpty = not { (array: [Int]) in array.isEmpty }
arrayNotEmpty([1, 3, 5]) // true
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. I would still like to work with a generic collection instead of `array: [Int]`. Isn't there a better way?